# h2 & linux. how to start the database?

Tags: database, linux, h2

sorry im rather new to linux ubuntu. i have an application that i made that runs with tomcat and connects to an h2 database. it all works fine on my windows laptop. im now moving it onto my linux computer to run all the time. but im having trouble with starting the database. i have downloaded h2 from their website. and its sitting on my desktop.

the question is. how to start the database.

and is their any other commands i need to know to run and operate it.

thankyous

Answer (score 1):

The H2 database supports different modes:

- You can use H2 in embedded mode using a database URL of the form `jdbc:h2:~/test`. This is the easiest case. In that case the database is running within the same process as your application is running, and you don't have to start a separate process just for the database.
- You can use H2 in server mode. In that case you need to start a separate server process. But for your case it doesn't sound like you need this, right?
- H2 also supports mixed mode (half embedded / half server), and the automatic mixed mode.

For details, see the H2 documentation about [Connection Modes](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes).

Comment: well on my windows comp which everything works fine i have to click on the h2 console which opens up the web browser with its bits and pieces where you can create databases/modify them etc. as soon as thats open my app works fine and can query/modify the db etc. pretty much all im wanting to know is how to launch the console/web page within linux as their is no icon i can double click on

Comment: After installing H2, there is a shell script `bin/h2.sh`, you can use that (first you need to make it runnable using `chmod +x h2.sh` I believe).

Comment: thank you very much! i'd tried so many variations of trying to run the h2.sh script in the bin folder. but as i noted i'm very new to linux and didn't know that runnable thingy. the "chmod +x h2.sh" is exactly what i needed. now it opens the console in the web browser. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/h2-database/r-qRnskN0eQ

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal in bin directory of h2 database and write these commands...

```
chmod +x h2.sh

./h2.sh
```

[Click here for more information (similar thread)...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575112/installing-and-starting-the-h2-database-on-ubuntu)